# Why are System.Net.WebSockets not event based?

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I would like to ask what is the reasoning behind System.Net.WebSockets not being event-based. In JS I just have to subscribe to events:

```
// Create WebSocket connection.
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    socket.send('Hello Server!');
});

// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
});
```

But in C# `System.Net.WebSockets`, events are not present at all. If I want to receive messages I have to do something like this:

```
while (true){
    byte[]? buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
    var result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
    string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
    // here I can call event.Invoke if i want to turn it into event-based
}
```

I can understand that this might be because of the fact that WebSockets in C# are on a lower level of abstraction than in JS and I should just implement the event logic by myself.

What I don't understand at all is the connection close detection. `System.Net.WebSockets` socket has a property `State` which contains information about the socket's current state and changes according to it.
As far as I understand, this property is the only way I can know if the socket was closed. Why can't I just listen to its change? Is it really my only option in the detection of the state of the socket to periodically poll this property? Again, I can implement the logic by myself but the effectivity will be lost (because of the polling). Why can't there just be an event that would fire every time this property is set?

Comment: You're using a raw socket, if you want to have events use a library e.g Signalr should handle what you want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebSockets are based in TCP sockets so they have implemented the same logic as in those. When a socket is closed and you have a loop waiting to receive it will receive 0 bytes and continue, so, if you check after each receive if the socket is closed you will know it immediately, something like this:

```
//Create the buffer only once, it's more efficient
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];

while (true)
{
    
    var result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

    if(socket.CloseStatus.HasValue) //Has the socket been closed?
    {
       Closed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);//your close event
       break;
    }

    string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
    Received?.Invoke(this, message); //Your receive event.
}
```